# add row from matrix a to matrix b by index in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization

I am trying to do the following computation in a more efficient (vectorized) way instead of a loop.

```py
for i in range(N):

  y[:,idx[i]] -= X[i]
```

where :

- `X` is N by D matrix,
- `y` is k by D matrix
- `idx` is a vector of length N with values between 0 and k-1

Example:

```
x = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])


y =  array([[100, 101, 102, 103],
           [104, 105, 106, 107],
           [108, 109, 110, 111]])

idx = array([2, 1, 1, 1, 2])
```

So the output should be:

```
y = array([[100, 101, 102, 103],
          [ 80,  78,  76,  74],
          [ 92,  91,  90,  89]])
```

and this is equivalent to :

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     y[idx[i],:] -= x[i]
```

Comment: Can you give  a simple example

Comment: `y[:,idx[i]]` or `y[idx[i],:]`?

Comment: I mean by giving matrix components like if a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]] and b = [7,8,9] and ind = [0, 1,2] what do you want to calculate or obtain ?

Answer (score 1):

Pandas solution is the shortest to go. You can do it via NumPy but a bit longer code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x, idx)
s = df.groupby(df.index).sum()
y[s.index] -= s
```

or in your case, since index are indices, you can directly use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
s = df.groupby(idx).sum()
y[s.index] -= s
```

output:

```
array([[100, 101, 102, 103],
       [ 80,  78,  76,  74],
       [ 92,  91,  90,  89]])
```

Comment: look above I just update my question to include an example

Comment: @AryehHoltzberg Please check out the edit on the post to include what you are looking for. Thank you

Comment: look at my example I want to substruct the row for each time the row number appear in the index vector so for row 2 in Y matrix i would substruct rows 1,2,3, and will get [ 80,  78,  76,  74]

Comment: @AryehHoltzberg I see. That would be stretching Numpy abilities. You can certainly do vectorized numpy for it, but Pandas is way more suited for such task(basically one-liner in Pandas). Can you use Pandas instead? If not, I can write a Numpy solution for it.

Comment: thanks pandas will be great and if you have a solution for numpy I will love to see just for learning

Comment: @AryehHoltzberg Please checkout my update on the code using pandas. Numpy solution would be long and I don't recommend it unless speed is crucial.

Comment: Tnx that exactly what i wanted!!

Comment: @AryehHoltzberg Glad it helped. Please feel free to accept/upvote the answer if it resolves the issue. Thank you